# Navigating upwards in directories asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I'm trying to use ../ sequence of characters to navigate one directory upwards in a asp.net application. Basically the web application calls a dll (added as a reference) with a path say ../../folder1/folder2/desired-file.txt. The called function in the dll reads the desired-file.txt and performs some action.

When i try debugging my web application and step into the function within the dll, the path (after removing the ../../ i.e. i specified desired-file.txt as the path) i get an exception:

```
"Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\desired-file.txt
```

Why is asp.net going to this path by default? In some other web application (when i specified path as ../../folder1/folder2/desired-file.txt), it was going to C:\Windows\folder1\folder2\desired-file.txt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [System.IO.Directory.GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) to get the upper folder